# Two wheels and a ball problem confusion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

When I was preparing for a job interview for chemistry, the following question appeared:

[image]

Now, my answer was as such:

> If the bigger wheel is rotated clockwise, the smaller wheel moves anticlockwise so the ball will move down and fall off the plank.

However, the answer (which was pretty brief) only mentioned the Centre of Masses being inline, so it will stay level.

I'm just left quite confused. Why is the Centre of Mass being "level" have any effect on this system?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is asking about the instant the wheel starts turning rather than what happens on a longer time scale?

Comment: Why would the smaller wheel spinning cause any motion above?  Would there be any motion beyond the two blue wheels spinning?

Comment: If both blue wheels have bearings (so they rotate freely) and the green bar can only move up and down, then there is no mechanism to impose any motion to the ball.

Comment: This is an ambiguous question.   How fast is the wheel being rotated?  If very fast, I would expect the ball's inertia to tend to hold it where it is, and as the table rotated under it, the ball would move up as the table rotated.  If the wheel is rotated slowly, the most appropriate answer seems to be that the ball would stay level for a very short amount of time, then roll down the incline.  More information is needed to answer the question.

Comment: I have no idea what this is supposed to be showing.  My original interpretation would be "no because this bar seems to be completely fixed in the only directions we would expect it to move by whatever those black/grey rectangles are".  Without more information this question is basically all guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

The drawing is not entirely clear, but I'll try...

Assuming that the black dots are bearings with axis normal to the picture, both blue wheels can rotate freely. The rotational motion of the small blue wheel is generated through an horizontal friction force. This force do not causes motion of the green bar since it is contained in the horizontal plane. The friction force has no vertical component because it is tangent to the contact surfaces. Therefore, there is no mechanism to impose any motion to the ball. If there is no ball motion and the wheels center of mass is in its centers, then the system's center of mass is not changed.

However, if the center of mass of the small wheel is not in its center, and assuming the big wheel is free to rotate but not to translate, then a small centrifugal force will move the ball in the vertical direction.

Note that the ball is not in a stable equilibrium position. Therefore any perturbation in the horizontal plane will make the ball move in this plane.